# How to Populate an ASP.NET Treeview Recursively?

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion, treeview

I have an ASP.NET treeview control that needs to be populated recursively from a series of objects.  At the minimum, I need to hierarchically display the category name and description for each source and parent node.  To this end, I've written the following in my codebehind page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using CATALooK.Automation;

namespace VBayUnMatched  
{
public partial class VBayCats : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private int id;
    private CATALooK.Automation.SourceInfo source;
    private CATALooK.Automation.CategoryInfo parent;
    private string catID;
    private string catName;
    private string desc;
    private string rawData;
    private int advCatID;
    private DateTime lastUpdated;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CategoryController cc = new CategoryController();
        CategoryInfo ci = new CategoryInfo
        (id,source,parent,catID,catName,desc,rawData,advCatID,lastUpdated);
        //CATALooK.AdvCatInfoRemote[] acir = cc.getAdvancedCategories();
        TreeView trvUnMatchedCats = new TreeView();
        TreeNodeCollection tnColl = new TreeNodeCollection();
        TreeNode nodeSource = new TreeNode { Value = ToString(source) };
        TreeNode nodeParent = new TreeNode { Value = ToString(parent) };
        TreeNode nodeName = new TreeNode { Value = catName };
    }

    private void PopulateTreeview()
    {


    }

    private string ToString(SourceInfo source)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private string ToString(CategoryInfo parent)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

}

How do I use recursion to assign parent to nodeParent, source to nodeSource and catName to nodeName?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and most readable) way is to create a class that implements the `IHierarchyData` interface. This exposes a node of a hierarchical data structure, including the node object and some properties that describe characteristics of the node. Objects that implement the IHierarchyData interface can be contained in `IHierarchicalEnumerable` collections, and are used by ASP.NET site navigation (like sitemaps) and data source controls.

a great sample of that is **[found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchydata.aspx#Y900)** and **[here you see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchicalenumerable.gethierarchydata.aspx)** how to create `IHierarchyData` in a recursive manner